# How to import Eclipse project with native library(using so files) in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, .so

When you try to import Eclipse project with native library(using so files) in Android studio ,after eclipse export project,and android studio import it, you will see the result(fail of loading library) like below:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[xxx]
>   couldn't find "yourlib.so"
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367) at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: If you need to add an explanation. Add it as a question and then you can post your answer

Comment: The new Documentation (Beta) section is exactly used for posting explanations, tutorials and examples like this one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export your eclipse file

   - in eclipse-> right click-> Export-> Generate Gradle build files-> next to finish
2. Creat JNI folder like this src/main/jni/ ,
   here two ways to do it

   - in android studio -> right click -> new -> folder -> JNI folder
   - or go to finder(or file manager) to deal with the folder thing

> in eclipse we usually put these stuff in a libs folder , but you have
>   to creat jniLibs yourself now

3. Put your so files to JNI folder
4. Set your Build gradle

   ```
   sourceSets {
       main {
           jni.srcDirs = []
           jniLibs {
               srcDir 'src/main/jni'
               srcDir 'src/main/libutility'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. done

hope this help, thx